Apple Widgets not updating Image
I am trying to load images on Widget for my app. For loading the Image I am using below code,
class ImageLoader: ObservableObject {
    @Published var image: UIImage? = nil
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil
    
    func load(from url: URL) {
        cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .map {
                UIImage(data: $0.data)
            }
            .replaceError(with: nil)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .assign(to: \.image, on: self)
    }
}

struct AsyncImageView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var loader = ImageLoader()
    let url: URL
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if let image = loader.image {
                Image(uiImage: image)
                    .resizable()
                    .clipped()
                    .scaledToFit()
            } else {
                Image(uiImage: UIImage())
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            loader.load(from: url)
        }
    }
}

And I am calling the above method from Body of Widget like below
AsyncImageView(url: URL(string: contentURL)!)

Issue is image is not getting loaded on Widget.

Widgets don’t observe they are like a gif

Correct me if I'm wrong, but Widgets are mainly statics.
Your main app should:

Call your web service
Download the images
Store them on the device in a shared directory between your app and your widget extension
Refresh your widget

And the widget will just have to check for images in the shared directory and display them statically.
